# rare High altitude balloon footage (highest peak before balloon burst 23034 metres) without fishe-eye lens

Tags: earth

Why does Earth  appear flat so HIGH UP in the sky?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDs2T2PgxNM

Comment: How do you expect it to look?

Comment: This is a question of one's perception, and also of the choice of an objective. Here is a similar video where they used a fisheye objective, and the same planet appears very round: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpPuESSbhAc

Answer (score 1):

"so high up": find the altitude, find the earth radius, compare. 
If you are in high-school or more, you shoud even by able to compute.